# Registering iOS app with MFP CLI 8.0 always prompts bundleId

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-cli

I'm trying to register iOS native apps to a Bluemix Mobile Foundation server (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mobile-foundation) using mfpdev CLI in an unattended way.

I've achieved that with sample apps available from the MobileFirst Operations Console but trying to use my own apps I get always the bundleId and version prompts for any operation: register, pull, push.

Those properties are already defined in Info.plist, so I don't know what else I should do to allow unattended operations:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.ibm.mobileappbuilder.Mytestapp</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
```

Comment: can you add your exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm this.

I've created a new iOS app and gave it the bundle identifier: com.sample.myapp

From command line I then did: mfpdev app register bluemix ("bluemix" being the name for my Mobile Foundation service instance on Bluemix).

This asked from me the following:

> idanadar@mbp-idan:~/Desktop/company$ mfpdev app register bluemix
>   Verifying server configuration...
>   Registering to server:'https://mobilefoundation-9x-server.mybluemix.net:443' runtime:'mfp'
>   ? Enter your bundleId: com.sample.myapp
>   To prevent future prompting for the bundle ID in iOS projects, update the '' element that corresponds to the 'CFBundleIdentifier' in your Info.plist file.
>   Registered app for platform: ios

Which passed successfully.
I then deleted the app from the console, and edited the info.plist accordingly:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.sample.myapp</string>
```

I tried the command again and this time it did not ask the question...